# How to start at Part 0 in LaTeX?

Tags: sectioning, parts

I have this code:

`\setcounter{part}{-1}`

to start part in my document at 0. It works, but the first part doesn't say 0. [image]

Comment: by default it would show a number assuming you used `\part` not `\part*` as you have shown no code impossible to guess what is wrong

Comment: unless you are numbering parts A, B, C or i, ii, iii as those schemes have no zero.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. Thank you very much!!! 

Edit: Looks like that might be wrong. It is very much possible to number it although the part is 0.

Comment: my comment was correct. I said there is no 0 in roman, you can of course have 0 in other number formats

Comment: No, not really. You said "unless you are numbering parts A, B, C or i, ii, iii." In that case, the alphabets don't contain a zero.

Comment: the "unless" was qualifying my earlier comment that it was impossible to guess, as I did make a (correct) guess as to the problem, despite the lack of information in the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're using the `article` document class, part-level headers are numbered with uppercase-Roman numerals: I, II, III, etc. Because the ancient Romans didn't know about the number "0", there's no Roman-numeral symbol that corresponds to the number "0".

If you *must* show a zero-numbered part-level header, you should switch to using Arabic -- or should that be Hindu-Arabic? -- numerals: `\renewcommand\thepart{\arabic{part}}`.

---

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand\thepart{\arabic{part}}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{part}{-1}
\part{Hello}
\part{World}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for but didn't think it was possible. It works great, thank you very much!!!!

Comment: @AshwinFernandez, fine :-) Then please accept the answer as solution ;-)